# How to concatenate PHP variable name?

Tags: php, variables, append, concatenation

I have a PHP for loop:

```
for ($counter=0,$counter<=67,$counter++){

echo $counter;
$check="some value";

}
```

What I am trying to achieve is use the for loop variable and append it to the name of another variable.

Bascially, I want the PHP output to be as follows for each row

```
1
$check1="some value"

2
$check2="some value"

3
$check3="some value"

4
$check4="some value"

etc etc
```

I have tried `$check.$counter="some value"` but this fails.

How can I achieve this? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Would the use of an `array` be preferable to this method? `$myVar = array(); for($i = 0; $i <= 67; $i++) { $myVar[] = "Some Value"; }`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The proper syntax for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) is:

```
${"check" . $counter} = "some value";
```

However,  I **highly discourage** this.  What you're trying to accomplish can most likely be solved more elegantly by using [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  Example usage:

```
// Setting values
$check = array();
for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 67; $counter++){
    echo $counter;
    $check[] = "some value";
}

// Iterating through the values
foreach($check as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, is there a situaton when this is acceptable or is it functionality no longer used?

Comment: @Smudger:  Off the top of my head,  I can't think of a solid case where one would use variable variables.  Looking at the [comments on the documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#usernotes) might give you some ideas on where they could be useful.  Just keep in mind that what you read there may not be considered best practice.

Comment: Concatenation is never the "cleaner" solution, but there may be cases where you have old, highly developed code that was never intended to correlate A+B where it is simply much easier to do this than rewriting hundreds of lines of code just to replace old variable types with arrays

Comment: The one case I can think of where I use them is with HTML forms where I have recursively built inputs.  When you Post it, it will post as a bunch of variables and not as an array; so, recursively calling them may be easier with $_POST[${"myInputName".$i}]

Answer (score 6):

You should use ${'varname'} syntax:

```
for ($counter=0,$counter<=67,$counter++){
    echo $counter;
    ${'check' . $counter} ="some value";
}
```

this will work, but why not just use an array?

```
$check[$counter] = "some value";
```

Answer (score 6):

This is usable in some cases. For example if your app has something like 2 language entries in DB.

```
echo $this->{'article_title_'.$language};
```

That's much more usable than for example this;

```
if($language == 'mylanguage1')
    echo $this->article_title_mylanguage1;
else
    echo $this->article_title_mylanguage2;
```

Obviously this is what you should not have to do in your multilingual app, but i have seen cases like this.

Comment: Yeah, it is my case: I got 3 columns entries in DB. So i need to loop like that from a checkboxes group

Answer (score 0):

An array would accomplish this.

```
$check = array();

for($counter = 0; $counter <= 67; $counter++) {
    $check[] = "some value";
    var_dump($check[$counter]);
}
```