# Is this the correct method to fetch and calculate SQL data?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, calculated-columns

I'm new to php and sql.  Today, I gave myself the task of fetching integer values from the sql db, then do some basic calculations.  **Is there anywhere else to reduce the code while still completing the task, or am I already down to the most fundamental level?  And am I over-executing anything in the process?**

My objectives were to;

1. Fetch db values from a column.
2. Get the average value from this column.
3. Then calculate a new average having excluded the highest and lowest values.

The following way my best attempt;

```
$con = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_test') ;

    $count = $con->query('SELECT COUNT(SP$) FROM `math`');
    $grp = $con->query('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SP$) FROM `math`');
    $min = $con->query('SELECT MIN(SP$) FROM `math`');
    $max = $con->query('SELECT MAX(SP$) FROM `math`');
    $sum = $con->query('SELECT SUM(SP$) FROM `math`');
    $avg = $con->query('SELECT AVG(SP$) FROM `math`');

    $count = $count->fetch_assoc();
    $grp = $grp->fetch_assoc();
    $min = $min->fetch_assoc();
    $max = $max->fetch_assoc();
    $sum = $sum->fetch_assoc();
    $avg = $avg->fetch_assoc();

    $count = $count['COUNT(SP$)'];
    $grp = $grp['GROUP_CONCAT(SP$)']; 
    $min = $min['MIN(SP$)'];
    $max = $max['MAX(SP$)'];
    $sum = $sum['SUM(SP$)'];
    $avg = $avg['AVG(SP$)'];
```

Display and Calculations as follows;

```
    echo "Sample Size: " . $count ."</br />";
    echo "Display Values:" . $grp ."</br />";
    echo "Sum of Values: " . $sum ."</br />";
    echo "Average: " . $avg ."</br /></br />";

    echo "Now find the new average, by excluding the highest and lowest value:";

    echo "Lowest Value: " . $min ."</br />";
    echo "Highest Value: " . $max ."</br />";

    echo "New Sum: " . ($sum - $max - $min) . "</br />";
    echo "New Average : " . (($sum - $max - $min) / ($count-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like this:

```
$con = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_test');
$operations = ["count"=>'COUNT(SP$)',
    "grp"=>'GROUP_CONCAT(SP$)',
    "min"=>'MIN(SP$)',
    "max"=>'MAX(SP$)'...];

foreach($operations as $name=>$value){
    $name = ${$name};
    $name = $con->query('SELECT '.$value.' FROM `math`');
    $name = $name->fetch_assoc();
    $name = $name[$value];
}
```

What is did is to put all the operations in an associative array (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and loop the array with a foreach statement.

Now, the variable names are composed using [PHP Variables - Concatenate variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740231/php-variables-concatenate-variable-name) . Note, this is not recommended but it exists and it works.

The code is not tested because I do not have PHP installed on my machine but it should be valid.

Comment: So you think I should stick with how I did it?

Comment: In the given context, because the output can't be parametrized so well I think that both ways are just as good. Just that one has more text and the other less.

Here is something easy to read for this issue:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/coding-standard.html

You are interested in this thing called "Coding standard" that should be followed by every PHP programmer.