# Can I generate instances of a class inside a for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I want to generate a class instance for each post value.

Something like this

```
$i=0;

foreach ($_POST['URL'] as $url) {
    $classInstance.$i = new className();
    $i++;
}
```

Each with a different name.

I read about variable variable names like:

```
${"classInstance" . $i} = new className();
```

But it's been previously discouraged in other questions ([PHP Variables - Concatenate variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740231/php-variables-concatenate-variable-name))

Is there any other way to achieve the same without using variable variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're proposing is perfectly valid. But there are not many justified use cases for using that piece of functionality for simply concatenating numbers to variables. If you need a collection of variables, simply aggregate those objects into a data structure such as an array or an [SPL List](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php), and manipulate them from there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the SPL List as it is the first time I've hear of it